# Site throwing error and crashing in IE 8

Tags: performance, internet-explorer

I am having an issue with a site I am working on throwing an error in IE 8. My client is reporting that anytime they go to the site and click on anything an error is then caused forcing the site to crash. This only seems to be happening in IE 8. I am on a mac and run windows only through boot camp. I cannot seem to replicate the problem, or debug it. I'm hoping someone here can replicate the error and advise me how to fix it. Here's a link to the site. http://www.eacpds.com Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: Crashed in IE9 too but I can't reproduce it.

Comment: Thanks ZippyV. I think I was able to solve it by moving a script called respond.js to the footer. Can you verify that this has also solved the issue you had in IE9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving `respond.js` to the footer seems to have done the trick if anyone else is having a similar issue.